# Can't read data from firebase realtime database on a flutter application on iOS and Android, but can write data

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are using firebase realtime database for our flutter project, we can both read and write data from the database when using it on our chrome application. But when we are using it on either android or iOS we can only write data to the database.

We have tried accessing different things from our database but what we are not being able to read anything. Our reads from flutter web application are always successful and correct. Have redownloaded both the googleService-Info.plist and also google-service.json. We don't get any error messages, we have used print statements that shows that nothing is picked up with iOS and android.

This is how we inizilize firebase.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This is an example of one method that works for chrome but not iOS and Android were:

- Chrome is able to print the JSON string.
- Android and iOS prints null.

```
    Future<Game?> getGame(String lobbyId) async {
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Games").child(lobbyId);
    try {
      DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();
      var s = event.snapshot.value;

      //Print statement to see the snapshot. 
      print(s.toString());
      if (s != null) {
        return Game.fromJson(s);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This is the function were getGame is getting called.

```
void _checkContinueQuiz(String lobbyId, BuildContext context{
    var ref =           FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Games").child(lobbyId);
    print("check");
    ref.onValue.listen((event) async {
  var snapshot = event.snapshot;
  Future<Game?> game = dbHelper.getGame(lobbyId);
  var gameData = await game;
  if (gameData!.updateQuiz) {
    dbHelper.setUpdateQuiz(widget.lobbyId, false);
    setStateNextQuestion();
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify what you man by "we get a null value"? If might be easier if you `print(s);` and show us that code and its output.

Comment: Does the code return null from the try block or catch block? The code that you propose return null also if you have an exception

Comment: Edited to post, to make it more clear, hope fully that helps a bit!.